# Lua "busted.runner" must be on every file

Tags: lua

I have a `tests.setup.lua` file that I want to use to initialize and register custom matchers. It looks like

```
-- tests.setup.lua
package.path = package.path .. ';../?.lua'

require 'busted.runner'()

require 'tests.mocks.ngx'
require 'tests.extensions.matchers'
require 'tests.extensions.spy'
```

Then a test file would have

```
package.path = package.path .. ';../?.lua'
require 'tests.setup'
```

However, running `lua the-testfile.lua` will not run any tests unless I specifically add `require 'busted.runner'()` to that file as well. Why is requiring it from `tests.setup` not enough?

Comment: What does "busted.runner" do?

Comment: @Phins - [Busted for dummies](https://olivinelabs.com/busted/)